# Python sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a Database on my PC using python and SQLite 3 using the code below, however when I attempt to run I get this error

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test_database')
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I'm quite new to this, so sorry if this is a simple mistake. Could someone tell me how i can fix this?

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('test_database') 
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bot_memory
          ([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [dateandtime] datetime, [task] varchar, [result] varchar)
          ''')
          
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I needed to install [SQLite](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/download-install-sqlite/) and [SQLite Studio](https://digitalfellows.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2016/04/08/fun-times-with-sqlite-or-a-beginners-tutorial-to-data-management-and-databases-with-sql/). Then, I can create and manage the Databases on my pc.